# Why i'm getting OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this method i'm calling the method each X seconds from a timer tick event.
In the first few seconds there are no problems but then after 20 seconds or it show the exception.

```
private void ReturnTexture(Texture texture_take, List<Point> lstPnt, float[] anglArr, float angle)
        {
            int i, j, bytes = 2048 * 512, stride = 2048;
            GraphicsStream textureStream;
            byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

            //sets texture to complete transparent
            GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(rgbValues, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            MemSet(gch.AddrOfPinnedObject(), 0x0, rgbValues.Length);

            //add 90 degrees because the cone starts at 90
            angle += 90F + 23.75F;

            //checks all points and draws yellow only those how are inside the cone
            if (lstPnt != null)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < lstPnt.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (anglArr[i] <= angle && anglArr[i] >= angle - 47.5F) //if point angle is inside cone. Cone angle is 47.5 degrees
                    {
                        j = lstPnt[i].Y * stride + lstPnt[i].X * 4;

                        //yellow
                        rgbValues[j + 0] = (byte)0;
                        rgbValues[j + 1] = (byte)255;
                        rgbValues[j + 2] = (byte)255;
                        rgbValues[j + 3] = (byte)255;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

The exception is on the line:

```
byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
```

When the exception happen i see that the variable bytes contain: 1048576
And rgbValues is null

I used a breakpoint before the exception happen and saw that the value in bytes was the same: 1048576 but the exception happen only after 20 seconds or so and not just in the beginning.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in Weather Radar.exe

```
System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024882
  Message=Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
  Source=Weather Radar
  StackTrace:
       at Weather_Radar.Form1.ReturnTexture(Texture texture_take, List`1 lstPnt, Single[] anglArr, Single angle) in d:\C-Sharp\Weather Radar\Weather Radar\Weather Radar\Form1.cs:line 314
       at Weather_Radar.Form1.timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\Weather Radar\Weather Radar\Weather Radar\Form1.cs:line 59
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at Weather_Radar.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\Weather Radar\Weather Radar\Weather Radar\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Line 314 in form1 is: byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

Line 59 in form1 is: ReturnTexture(scannedCloudsTexture, cloudPoints, angleArray, angleF);

This is the timer tick event code:

```
static float angle_ = 0.0F;
        static float angleF = 0.0F;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (angleF > 360F)
            {
                angleF -= 360F;
            }

            ReturnTexture(scannedCloudsTexture, cloudPoints, angleArray, angleF);

            DisplayOnScreen(angle_);

            angle_ += (float)(Math.PI * 1d / 180d);
            angleF += 1.0F;
        }
```

Comment: GCHandle is protected from Garbage Collector, so you should free the memory usage calling GCHandle.Free method when the handle are no more necessary

Comment: I bet every timer tick your RAM increases. Try to reuse your array and not create on every tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comment by Renuiz, it looks like you are not freeing memory allocated for your image. When you call `GCHandle.Alloc`

> A new GCHandle that protects the object from garbage collection. This GCHandle must be released with Free when it is no longer needed.

If you do not `Free` the `GCHandle`, the 1MB allocated by your code will never be released. I think there are two possible options:

- Reuse the `byte[]` if possible, not requiring more memory. Keep the `GCHandle` so you can memset them to zeroes each tick.
- Do not pin the `byte[]` in memory using the `GCHandle`. When you create a new `byte[]` [all values will be set to zero](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691346(v=vs.71).aspx) anyways.